# CakePHP Repassando Informações Entre Controllers

Tags: php, cakephp

Como faço para repassar informações entre dois controllers, exemplo:

Eu tenho no meu banco de dados duas tabelas, uma de usuários e outra de livros, aí eu seleciono um livro que está na tabela livros, pego seu id e tenho que atualizar essa informação na tabela do usuário..

Eu tenho dois controllers, um de usuários e outro de livros, eu tenho que repassar o id do livro para o controller de usuários..

1. Como passo essa informação entre controllers
2. Como seleciono o id do usuário logado no sistema
3. Qual o jeito correto de fazer essa atualização

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No [**cookbook**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt) você pode ver um método chamado [`loadModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel), com ele é possível vocês utilizar o *Model* de usuários dentro do seu *controller* livros.

### Exemplo:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$users = $this->User->find('all');
```

Caso queira carregar um dado específico de outro Model você pode usar:

```
$this->loadModel('Livro', 2);
$livro = $this->Livro->read();
```

Caso você tenha feito o relacionamento corretamente entre as tabelas e criado os *Models* corretamente você pode usar o sequinte para manipular os dados relacionados

```
$users = $this->User->Livro->find('all');
$livros = $this->Livro->User->find('all');
```

Para obter os dados do usuário logado no cakephp você pode utilizar a seção ou o *component Auth*

### Auth

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

### Session

```
$this->Session->read('User.id');
```